# ggplot alignment of sf-plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-raster

I'm having a problem with aligning two sf-plots. I want to make a classic "zoom in"-map, i.e., two maps, one of a continent and the other of a smaller region.

However I am having problems with the alignment/scaling of the two plots because the shapefiles I'm plotting are different sizes (see the reprex with Austria and Germany)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)

### get shapefiles and convert to sf
aut<-st_as_sf(getData('GADM',country="AUT",level=1,path=getwd()))
ger<-st_as_sf(getData('GADM',country="DEU",level=1,path=getwd()))

### create individual ggplots
aut.gg<-ggplot()+theme_classic()+
  geom_sf(aut, mapping=aes())

ger.gg<-ggplot()+theme_classic()+
  geom_sf(ger, mapping=aes())

## make a multipanel plot pretty enough to show other people
plot_grid(ger.gg, aut.gg, nrow=1, axis="l", align="h", labels=c("A","B"))
grid.arrange(ger.gg, aut.gg, nrow=1)
```

Problem with plot_grid: while the axes are nicely aligned, Austria does NOT look like that, it is somehow "squished" for alignment.

Problem with grid.arrange: I would like the plots to be tob-justified and not centered.

So I'm basically stuck between a rock and a hard place ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps patchwork helps?

You can use patchwork `plot_layout()` function to control the relative sizes of the plots.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(patchwork)


ger.gg + aut.gg
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>